# How to put link to the table cell using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Below there is simple/example table.
For the question is on how can I ***put a link for the particular table cell*** that I need.
For example, when i ***click on the first cell of the table "row 1, cell 1"***, so it will ***execute the link and jump to the next site***.

```
<table border="1">
     <tr>
         <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
         <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
         <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Thanks for for SHARING.

Comment: What link are you trying to execute?

Comment: Put anchor tag between <td>

Comment: I fail to see how this is a JQuery question.

Comment: are you trying to change pages with the click, or move the window to the next table cell?

Comment: @koerbcm Yup..I'm try to change the pages once I click on the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your specified table cell an id (such as "linker") and then add a click event handler

**jQuery**:

```
$("td#linker").click(function(e)
{
    // Make your content bold
    $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
    // Direct the page like a link
    window.location.href="<WHER YOU WANT IT TO GO>";
    // Prevent the click from going up the chain
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="linker">Click Me</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the [a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag:

```
<td><a href="example.com">row 1, cell 1</a></td>
```

Just replace the href value with whatever site you are trying to link to.

**Update for jQuery:**

If you're trying to do so with jQuery, you first need to add some sort of unique identifier/selector to your desired td (such as a class, or ordinal position), and then add the anchor tag.  Let's just call the td select 'yourTd' for now:

```
 var aTag = $('<a>', {href: 'example.com' });
 aTag.text($('.yourTd').text());// Populate the text with what's already there

 $('.yourTd').text('').append(aTag);// Remove the original text so it doesn't show twice.
```

Comment: The question was about how to add the links using jquery. I'm assuming he has the table structure built already and needs to add links dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ability to override links within td's use the following code.  Also use $('body') if you will be adding additional records via ajax.

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr data-url="/yourlink">
<td>test</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td class="custom_url">
<a href="youroverridelink">link</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $('body').on('click','.table > tbody > tr > td', function() {
        window.location = $(this).not('.custom_url').parent().data('url');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JQuery way of doing it:-

```
$('<a>',{
    text:'row 1, cell 1',
    href:'http://www.google.com'       
}).appendTo('tr:first td:nth-child(1) ');
```

HTML:-

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
 <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RhWgf/343/)**

Answer (score 0):

First add class on the html td elements you want to make links on, something like:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="link">row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="link">row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then use jQuery to make links inside `td` elements

```
$('td.link').each(function() {
    $(this).html('<a href="google.com">' + $(this).html() + '</a>')
});
```